# Using digested password with Apache common Email

Tags: java, apache, email, authentication, jakarta-mail

So I've been looking at the email package provided in apache's org.apache.commons.mail. The basic tutorial is simple , straightforward, and works well.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html

The problem I am experiencing is that I don't wish to create cleartext passwords.  What I wish to do instead is to hash the password using MD5, store it that way, then create an email later at the appropriate time. The important thing is not to store a cleartext password in the system.

Reviewing the wiki article on SMTP Authentication
implies there are at least three methods to do this -- DIGEST-MD5, CRAM-MD5, and MD5 itself.

Googling, however, does not reveal any obvious way to make this happen with apache. It appears that Jetty wrote their own digestauthenticator to replace Apache's DefaultAuthenticator.

http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/security/authentication/DigestAuthenticator.html

And Apache's Tomcat likewise has a DigestAuthenticator.

However, since neither of these inherit from 
javax.mail.Authenticator

I can't simply swap them in.

So ... is there a *simple* way to configure org.apache.commons.mail.Email and its children to use digest authentication?  I haven't been able to find any examples or tutorials , nor have I been able to find anything on kindle.  But given that no one's used cleartext since about 1975 , I can't imagine this setting doesn't exist.

Respectfully,

Brian P.

Comment: Even with those MD5-based authentication mechanisms, you still need to have the clear text password available.  The difference is that the password isn't sent over the wire.  You can control which authentication mechanisms are used using [JavaMail properties](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html), which I assume you can set through commons email.

Comment: Thank you. So what you're telling me is, reading the document, that the arguments I pass in on this line

tr.connect(smtphost, username, password);

must still be in cleartext. Is that correct?  It'll send a digested version of the password, but the parameter itself must be cleartext. Correct? 

That ... isn't what I wanted.  What I wanted to do was to digest the password here and pass in the digested password as the argument, not the cleartext version. Are you saying that can't be done ?

Also ... while you'd think we could set the properties through commons, The docs don't reflect that.

Comment: Yes, the password parameter to the connect method must be clear text, the actual password.  If you "digest" the password, you're effectively just creating a different password.  If you could pass it to the server when connecting, then anyone who had that digested password could also pass it when connecting.  The way the MD5-based authentication mechanisms work is that the server and the client exchange messages that are "encryped" using the real password known to both of them, allowing the client to prove it knows the password without sending it to the server.

Comment: You might want to look into [OAuth2 authentication](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2), which is much more complicated but may better fit your needs.

Comment: *More* complicated?   

...

I think what I shall do instead is use javax.crypto.Cypher and related classes to encrypt the password which I store. Then, when I'm ready to send an email, I'll decrypt the password back to cleartext, then use it with the call above.  I'll still need to choose an encryption method, a key, and a place for the key, but technically it should be more secure because you can't simply intercept an encryption and use it in place of the password, as you can with a hash.

Comment: Jan, I''m trying to accept your comment as  the answer to the question.  I don't seem to be able to.  Could you click on "Answer this question" so I can accept the answer and give you credit?

Comment: Encrypting the key at rest is a good start.  Java keystores can do that for you, you don't have to implement it yourself.  The only problem then is how to pass the encryption key to your program such that other processes can't see it.